# Where should I ask CPU pipelines/cache related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have quite a few questions of the type of *finding average access times in CPU pipelines* under various conditions, *finding access times of caches* and the like. Would [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User) be the site to ask these, or some other site?

Comment: "Finding" how precisely?

Comment: I have the numerical values and such...so i need to know how to use them to infer the answer..

Comment: Do you mean you've got the theoretical (spec) values for these times, and you're trying to find out their actual values "experimentally" (using your own code) or something like that?

Comment: This sounds perfectly on-topic for SO to me...

Comment: Mmm... Questions about hardware. If it's got programming involved, then shoot away on [so]. I love these type of questions. :)

Comment: @Mysticial : Nope..no programming involved..:/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find ready-made benchmarks to run on your PC, that's computer usage: ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If it's not a PC but an iPhone, ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). If it's an Android phone, ask on [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/). If the computer is running a unix variant, ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

If you're want to know how to write benchmarks to measure characteristics of a chip, that's programming: ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

If you want to understand the theoretical concepts behind hardware design or compilation techniques, that's computer science: ask on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

If you are working with hardware, ask on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). The site does have a few questions relating to software, but [that is marginal](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-much-software-is-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks !! Its not related to software...actually its like finding average access times for memory given their hit ratios while accessing them, finding speed-up of CPU pipelines given various conditions and the like !!

Answer (score 2):

While it is quite theoretical/leaning towards computer science, I would post it on http://electronics.stackexchange.com. They are not discussing resistors only there ;)

Comment: That highly depends on what exactly the OP intends to ask, I'd say. You are an active participant on the Electronics SE? Your profile seems to indicate otherwise. Personally I'm not, so a recommendation from an active user would be welcome.

Comment: No, I am not active there, but I am a CE grad student and from a small random sample of questions asked there the OP's question (or what it would probably evolve to after feedback ;) looks as if it would fit there to me.

Comment: It's actually not so clear that software is welcome on EE.SE: [I asked for clarification](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-much-software-is-on-topic), and what I got wasn't really clear either.

Comment: Well, consider this sort of a question - Given some values for memory and cache access times and the related hit ratios for performing reads and writes on them, what is the average access time..would that be suitable for electronics ??